# Subversive: Commit selected text only (BPQ)

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

If i got a task (ie HT-4949311) and i

- fix the bug
- and change the javadoc

... in the same File.

And i like to seperate these two changes by two different comments:

- "HT-4949311: bugfix."
- "HT-4949311: javadoc."

... i need to:

1. revert the javadoc-change,
2. commit the bugfix,
3. write the javadoc-change again,
4. commit the javadoc-change.

Is there a better way to do so?

Or is there any feature that lets me simple commit the selected lines only?